# Laravel S3 file upload : fopen(path to file) failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I am uploading files to S3 :

In file system i have :

```
'default' => 's3',

'cloud' => 's3',

's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => '***********',
            'secret' => '********************',
            'region' => '************',
            'bucket' => '*************',
        ],

    ],
    'parent_url' => 'http://54.169.67.54/',

];
```

Everything seems fine but error comes up when upload a file.

`fopen(/var/www/html/project/public/photos/profile-pics/1-medium-1470892864.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: You need to change bucket policies. Check this link:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

Comment: Is it bucket permission issue ?

Comment: Ohh!! Seems you are getting file from your local system. make sure you have enough permission to access it. if you will face s3 bucket permission issue then refer above link.

Comment: The error suggests to me that the path to the file you are trying to upload doesn't exist, or you don't have local file permissions on the file/parent folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [League\Flysystem](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem)   and check [this](http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/api/) for further reference

Example :

```
    public function uploadFile( $getFile )
        {
            try{       

                $datetimefilename   =   Carbon::now()->format('YmdHis');             
                $ext                =   $getFile->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $filename           =   sprintf('%s.%s', $datetimefilename,$ext);
                $uploadPath         =   env('UPLOAD');

                if( Storage::disk('s3')->has($uploadPath) === false ){
                    Storage::disk('s3')->createDir($uploadPath);
                }

                $filePath           =   sprintf('%s/%s',$uploadPath,$filename);

                $result =  Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($getFile->getRealPath()));


                return $result ;
            }
            catch(\Exception $e)
            {   
                return false;
            }
        }
```